# Cant copy from my local machine to my online server even as a root user

Tags: server, 20.04, sudo, copy, scp

I am trying to copy a folder as a root user from my local machine to my server using the command

```
sudo scp -r simple-app.zip james@ip:/home/jobs
```

But I keep getting permission denied every time. And this is after I have logged into my server successfully.

I need help doing this.

Comment: Please copy and paste the command you tried and output from the terminal in your question, formatted as code. For one, it is unlikely that you succeeded with the command `Sudo`. . Perhaps one of the issues is that you do not tell where to copy on the server. That you are root on your local machine does not imply you are also root on the remote machine.

Comment: Use the {_} icon above the [edit question window](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1372396/edit) to format the pasted output as `code`.

Answer (score 2):

You are running `scp` command as root on your local computer. But you are not root at  your remote computer - you are james there. Check if james has write permissions in `/home/jobs` or maybe you missspell destination folder and it should be `/home/james/jobs`?

Comment: Thank you. It worked

Comment: Excellent! Please mark this answer as correct for future answer searchers.